# c# como se acomoda mediante el abcdedario NO ASCII

Tags: c#

Tengo un array  'wSaAd' quiero ordenar un array en este orden 'AadSw' pero pues el metodo ascii me lo ordena asi 'ASadw' que debo hacer???
este es mi metodo, abajo estaba haciendo un para si era de 90 para arriba que son las minusculas me lo hiciera a mayuscula pero hacer todo a mayusculas no es una opcion viable

```
  public void iniciarVector()
    {
        //CREACION DEL VECTOR
        char valoringresar;
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length; i++)
        {
            n++;
            valoringresar = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            numeros[n] = valoringresar;
        }

        //SE ORDENAN
        for (int r = 0; r < numeros.Length; r++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numeros.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (numeros[j] > numeros[j + 1])
                {
                    char aux = numeros[j];
                    numeros[j] = numeros[j + 1];
                    numeros[j + 1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }

     /*   for (int r = 0; r < numeros.Length; r++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numeros.Length-1; j++)
            {

                if (numeros[j] >= 90)
                {
                   numeros[j] = (char)(numeros[j] - 32);
                }
                
                if (numeros[j] > numeros[j + 1])
                {  
                    char aux = numeros[j];
                    numeros[j] = numeros[j + 1];
                    numeros[j + 1] = aux;
                }
                ;
               
            }
        }*/ 


    }
```

Comment: Aunque sean parecidos, C y C++ no son el mismo lenguaje. C# es otro mundo. Podrías usar [`Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). De forma simple: `str.OrderBy(x => char.ToLower(x))` o poner los caracteres en un `List` y usar su función `Sort` con  un comparador parecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casi lo tenías, tienes que colocar en mayúsculas (o minúsculas) tanto j como j+1. Esto en variables auxiliares, porque es solo para comparar.

```
for (int r = 0; r < chars.Length; r++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < chars.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        //NUEVO CODIGO -------------------
        char charX = chars[j];
        char charY = chars[j + 1];

        if (charX >=65 && charX <= 90 )
        {
            charX = (char)(charX + 32);
        }
        if (charY >= 65 && charY <= 90)
        {
            charY = (char)(charY + 32);
        }


        if (charX > charY) //FIN NUEVO CODIGO -------------------
        {
            char aux = chars[j];
            chars[j] = chars[j + 1];
            chars[j + 1] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: aaaaaa muchas gracias yussef! saludos desde torreon coah

Comment: @PabloVazquezAlvarado Que bueno te haya servido, no olvides marca la respuesta como correcta. Saludos desde Santiago